# How to exclude from subquery in aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say there are 2 collections `User` and `Exclude`.

`User` fields:

- user
- location

`Exclude` fields:

- userA
- userB

I want to get users near a location. If the user who executes the query is in `Exclude` as `userA` then exclude `userB` from results. If the executing user is in `Exclude` as `userB` then exclude `userA` from results.

For example:

```
// User collection
{
  { user: "1", location: [1, 1] },
  { user: "2", location: [1, 1] },
  { user: "3", location: [1, 1] },
  { user: "4", location: [1, 1] },
}

// Exclude collection
{
  { userA: "1", userB: "2" },
  { userA: "3", userB: "1" },
}
```

If user `1` executes the query, then it should only return:

```
{
  { user: "1", location: [1, 1] },
  { user: "4", location: [1, 1] },
}
```

because:

- user `2` is in `Exclude` collection with user `1`
- user `3` is in `Exclude` collection with user `1`

The query runs on `User` collection, but I can't figure out how to go about it:

```
{
  'geoNear': {
    'near': {
      'type': 'Point',
      'coordinates': [longitude, latitude]
    },
    'maxDistance': 100,
    'key': 'location',
    'spherical': true,
    'distanceField': 'dist',
    'includeLocs': 'loc',
    'query': {
      'user': {
        '$nin': {
          // subquery?
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does each `Exclude` document only have a pair of users that mutually exclude each other?

Comment: to get the difference, you can use lookup, and exclude a document if it "joined"(not empty array), but this is solution is not related to geonear

Comment: @rickhg12hs no, it may well be that there is only user 1 excluding user 2, but user 2 not excluding user 1.

Comment: @Takis_ interesting approach, so that would not be in `query` of `geoNear` but a following pipeline stage? I assume I'd have to add 2 new lookups stages (userA, userB), each one trying to join. Then add a 3rd `match` stage where I remove documents where any of the 2 lookups had a match. Correct?

Comment: " user 1 excluding user 2, but user 2 not excluding user 1." How would the `Exclude` collection indicate that?

Comment: @rickhg12hs If you look at the example in my OP, it is exactly that situation. User 1 excludes user 2, but user 2 doesn't exclude user 1, otherwise there would be an additional `{ userA: "2", userB: "1" }`. However, it is irrelevant whether user 1 excludes user 2, or user 2 excludes user 1, or both exclude each other. In any case, if user 1 is the executing user, user 2 should not be in the results.

Comment: @Takis_ I chose to go with your answer, as it's highly scalable compared to trying to fetch a list of all excluded users. If you write this as an answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: @Manuel The why isn't `{ user: "3", location: [1, 1] }` included in your example query output?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Because when user 1 executes the query then `{ userA: "3", userB: "1" }` means that user 3 won't be in the results. Again, it doesn't matter whether user 3 is `userA` or `userB`. User 3 is excluded if it appears in *any* combination with user 1 in the `Exclude` collection.

Comment: @Manuel So, likewise, user 1 would be excluded by by a query by user 3?